# Browsing large JSON file

Tags: json, path, key, schema, jq

I have a huge JSON file with some very deep paths.  I was hoping to use `jq` to show the top N keys with the deeper contents hidden.  And then once I find the keys I'm interesting in, keep drilling down, only showing me N levels down from my starting point similar to a text editors ability to fold everything below N levels.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: What does "huge" mean? How deep is "deep"?  Is the file a single JSON entitiy or a collection of them?  What do you mean by "browse"? By drilling down, do you mean increasing the value of N? If a fuzzy question deserves a fuzzy answer, I'd respond: "It will probably be worth your time learning jq." But I'd also ask: Have you thought about an alternative way of finding the "interesting" keys?

Comment: @ceejayoz Try what?

Comment: @peak I tried clarifying the question.  The answer below gets me close to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in viewing objects at a specific depth, you could utilize `getpath` and `paths`.  `paths` will return paths to all values in the graph.  You could filter those paths to paths of specific lengths then get the corresponding value using `getpath`.

e.g., looking at all values at depth 3 from the current object

```
getpath(paths | select(length == 3))
```

Then you could filter and narrow it down as you as you go.

Comment: This is getting close to what I want.  I would change to: `paths | select(length < 3)`  I don't want the actual contents, just the keys to get a feel for what data is available.

Answer (score 0):

Appended is a jq schema-inference program that can be useful for understanding the structure of a large JSON object or array of JSON entities, at least if there is some rhyme or reason behind it.

Usage: if the JSON entity of interest is in a file, input.json, then assuming the program below is in schema.jq, run:

```
jq -f schema.jq input.json
```

For a very large file, the schema inference might be slow, but typically it's faster to do it this way than using some kind of iterative method.  See, for example, the remarks following the example given next.

#### Example

Here's an example using JSON=JEOPARDY_QUESTIONS1.json, a 54MB file (55554625 bytes) 
available from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alicemaz/super_jeopardy/master/JEOPARDY_QUESTIONS1.json

```
$ time jq -c -f schema.jq $JSON
[
  {
    "air_date": "string",
    "answer": "string",
    "category": "string",
    "question": "string",
    "round": "string",
    "show_number": "string",
    "value": "string"
  }
]

real    0m12.868s
user    0m11.713s
sys     0m0.342s
```

The u+s time is noteworthy because it's about two-thirds of the u+s time on the same machine for the approach using the streaming parser to generate a synopsis of the paths (see synopsis.jq on this page).  This is perhaps counterintuitive given that the JSON file is an array of length 216,930.

#### schema.jq

```
# Schema inference
# Version 0.1
# Author: pkoppstein at gmail dot com
# Requires: jq 1.4 or higher

# This module defines three filters:
#   typeof/0 returns the extended-type of its input;
#   typeUnion(a;b) returns the union of the two specified extended-type values;
#   schema/0 returns the typeUnion of the extended-type values of the entities
#    in the input array, if the input is an array,
#     otherwise it simply returns the "typeof" value of its input.

# Each extended type can be thought of as a set of JSON entities,
# e.g. "number" for the set of JSON numbers, and ["number"] for the
# set of JSON number-valued arrays including [].

# The extended-type values are always JSON entities.
# The possible values are:
# "null", "boolean", "string", "number";
# "scalar" for any combination of non-null scalars;
# [T] where T is an extended type;
# an object all of whose values are extended types;
# "JSON" signifying that no other extended-type value is applicable.

# The extended-type values are defined recursively:
# The extended-type of a scalar value is its JSON type.
# The extended-type of a non-empty array of values all of which have the
#      same JSON type, t, is [t], and similarly for ["scalar"], and ["JSON"].
# The extended-type of [] is ["null"], since that is the extended type of all arrays
#     which have no elements other than null.
# The extended-type of an object is an object with the same keys, but the
#     values of which are the extended-types of the corresponding values.

# typeUnion(a;b) returns the least extended-type value that subsumes both a and b.
# For example:
#  typeUnion("number"; "string") yields "scalar";
#  typeUnion({"a": "number"}; {"b": "string"}) yields {"a": "number", "b": "string"};
#  typeUnion("null", t) yields t for any valid extended type, t.

def typeUnion(a;b):
  def scalarp: . == "boolean" or . == "string" or . == "number" or . == "scalar";
  a as $a | b as $b
  | if $a == $b then $a
    elif ($a | scalarp) and ($b | scalarp) then "scalar"
    elif $a == "JSON" or $b == "JSON" then "JSON"
    elif ($a|type) == "array" and ($b|type) == "array" then [ typeUnion($a[0]; $b[0]) ]
    elif ($a|type) == "object" and ($b|type) == "object" then
      ((($a|keys) + ($b|keys)) | unique) as $keys
      | reduce $keys[] as $key ( {} ; .[$key] = typeUnion( $a[$key]; $b[$key]) )
    elif $a == "null" or $a == null then $b
    elif $b == "null" or $b == null then $a
    else "JSON"
    end ;

def typeof:
  def typeofArray:
    if length == 0 then ["null"]
    else [reduce .[] as $item (null; typeUnion(.; $item|typeof))]
    end ;
  def typeofObject:
    reduce keys[] as $key (. ; .[$key] |= typeof) ;

  . as $in
  | type
  | if . == "string" or . == "number" or . == "null" or . == "boolean" then .
    elif . == "object" then $in | typeofObject
    else $in | typeofArray
    end ;

# Omit the outermost [] for an array
def schema:
  if type == "array" then reduce .[] as $x ("null";  typeUnion(.; $x|typeof))
  else typeof
  end ;



# Example top-level:
schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a filter which emits a stream of synopses of all the paths of
length <= depth in the input entity, except that if depth <= 0, the
depth limitation is ignored.

The synopsis of a path [p1, p2, ...] is constructed by replacing
integer components with ".[]", and prefixing string components with ".",
so for example, if i and j are integers, then
[i, "keyname", j] would be represented as .[].keyname.[]

Here is an example of the output produced using `jq -r`:

```
.[]
.[].data
.[].data.children
.[].data.modhash
.[].kind
```

#### paths_synopsis/1

```
# If depth<0 then select paths of length equal to -depth    
def paths_synopsis(depth):
  [ paths
  | if depth > 0 then select(length <= depth)
    elif (depth < 0) then select(length == -depth)
    else . end
  | [.[]|if type=="number" then "[]" else . end]]
  | unique
  | .[]
  | "." + join(".")
  ;
```

#### Very large JSON entities

jq has a streaming parser intended for use with very large JSON entities.

The following filter is intended for use with the jq streaming parser (jq --stream)
in a pipeline, the second component of which uniquifies the synopses as illustrated in this example:

```
jq --arg depth 0 -c --stream -f synopsis.jq input.json | sort -u
```

In the following formulation, the desired DEPTH limit must be specified on the command line.
Specify 0 for no limit.

synopsis.jq

```
# Usage: jq --arg depth DEPTH -c --stream -f synopsis.jq input.json | sort -u
# or:    jq --arg depth DEPTH -c --stream -f synopsis.jq input.json | jq -s -c unique[]
def synopsis(depth):
  select(length == 2)
  | .[0]
  | if depth > 0 then select(length <= depth)
    elif (depth < 0) then select(length == -depth)
    else . end
  | map( if type=="number" then [] else . end) ;

synopsis( $depth | if . then tonumber else 0 end )
```

#### Example:

```
curl -Ss 'http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?FcstType=json&lat=39.56&lon=-104.85' |
  jq --arg depth 0 -c --stream -f synopsis.jq |
  sort -u | head -n 50
```

`["creationDate"]
["creationDateLocal"]
["credit"]
["currentobservation","Altimeter"]
["currentobservation","Date"]
["currentobservation","Dewp"]
["currentobservation","Gust"]
["currentobservation","Relh"]
["currentobservation","SLP"]
["currentobservation","Temp"]
["currentobservation","Visibility"]
["currentobservation","Weather"]
["currentobservation","Weatherimage"]
["currentobservation","WindChill"]
["currentobservation","Windd"]
["currentobservation","Winds"]
["currentobservation","elev"]
["currentobservation","id"]
["currentobservation","latitude"]
["currentobservation","longitude"]
["currentobservation","name"]
["currentobservation","state"]
["currentobservation","timezone"]
["data","hazard",[]]
["data","hazardUrl",[]]`